# How to send emails in the same thread in Django?

Tags: python, django, email

I am wondering how can I send email in the same email thread using django.core.mail. I have an APIView that handles post requests from my contact form. It receives the contact form input and sends it to my email. In case when the email address from form input was already used (e.g. first form was submitted with mistakes), I would like such forms to be sent in the same email thread, rather than in separate emails. So basically every thread should contain submitted forms with the same email address as replies to the original email.

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import ContactFormSerializer
from rest_framework import status
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import strip_tags


class ContactFormAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ContactFormSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            contact_form = serializer.save()
            subject = 'New Contact Form Submitted'
            context = {
                'name': contact_form.name,
                'email': contact_form.email,
                'subject': contact_form.subject,
                'message': contact_form.message,
                'submitted_at': contact_form.submitted_at,
            }
            html_content = render_to_string('api/contact_form.html', context)
            text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
            email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                subject, text_content, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to=[settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
        )
        email.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')

        try:
            email.send()
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'detail': f'Failed to submit the contact form: {str(e)}'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

        return Response({'detail': 'Contact form submitted successfully.'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If two contact forms with the same email address were submitted, my APIView just sends them two times as separate emails.

Current behavior:

[image: two different emails even though email address in two contact forms is the same]

Desired behavior:

[image: contact forms with the same email just stack in the same email thread to avoid creating new emails]

Every idea is appreciated.

Comment: Email threading is not a function of the sending server. It's a function of the application used to receive and read them. Some apps would display your mails like you want anyway, just bevause they come from the same source and have the same title.